# how to print specific NNs of a sentence with spaCy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, spacy

Hi I need help with spaCy, what I'm trying to do is extract specific NNs from a sentence I give as input. 
By looking at the little code here let's say I want to use the sentence "the cat is better than a dog and a wolf".
I would like to extract just the first and the third NN and assign them each one to a random variable. how can I do that? the code for now just prints every NN in the sentence. thank you.

```
import spacy

frase1 = input('> \n\n')
nlp = spacy.load('en')
for t in nlp(frase1):
    if t.tag_ in ['NN']:
        print(t.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get NNs by their position in the sentence (in your example, the first and third), you could do it like this:

```
import spacy
import operator
nlp = spacy.load("en")

doc = nlp("The cat is better than a dog and a wolf.")
nns = [i.text for i in doc if i.tag_ == "NN"]
first, third = list(operator.itemgetter(0, 2)(nns))
```

If you just want the total number of NNs, you can do:

```
len(nns)
```

Comment: thank you! it worked :) but what if I want to print out the number of NN words? for example in the sentence "the cat is better than a dog and a wolf" it should give me "3" as output, can I do that?

Comment: Updated to include code for that. The length of the `nns` vector will give you the total number of `nns`.